# Is there a way to delete a tag?

Tags: support, tags

I was creating a tag for **[this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/209146/beating-the-hermit-mission-in-ring-runner)** question, and I accidentally created two, one of them that is incorrect (late night mistype). Is there a way to delete the incorrect tag?

**[This](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ring-runner-fots)** tag is the correct one, while **[here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ring-runner-ftos)** is the incorrect one (that should be dealt with).

Comment: Just delete it.  I believe there's a daily sweep that deletes tags no longer in use.

Comment: Just delete it? (I don't usually delve into the land of tags, so if you could explain it to me here)

Comment: As in, remove it from your question, and it will be purged

Comment: Oh, I had already replaced the tag with a proper one (the improper one has no question linked to it). So, daily, all tags without questions get deleted?

Comment: That is correct m

Comment: Well, maybe not dupe, but definitely related...

Comment: In case you were worried at seeing the tag page @ShadowZ. - you can literally see this page for any combination of characters that may make up a tag, like [tag:sdadawdafgvrdhd] for example.

Comment: >inb4 someone makes 'sdadawdafgvrdhd' into an actual game just to make my comment moot :/